# Writing to file using python move content to new line

Tags: python, file

I am trying to create a python program to read values from a file and write them to another file with some formatting. Let me explain my task fully!

I have a file with values of image pixels in a hexadecimals.

> AA
>
> 12
>
> C5
>
> 95
>
> ...

I want to convert this list of values in to a format like this

> 0:   AA;
>
> 1:   12;
>
> 2:   C5;
>
> 3:   95;
>
> ...

I have the following code with me

```py
def makeAddress(address, HEX):
    return str("\t%s    :   %s;" % (address, HEX));

imageFile = open("Image.txt", "r")
mifFile = open("INSTRUCTION_FILE.mif", "w")

address = 0;

for line in imageFile:
    mifFile.write(makeAddress(address, line))
    address = address + 1;

imageFile.close()
mifFile.close()
```

But when I try to run this program, the output is;

> 0:   AA
>
> ; 1:   12
>
> ; 2:   C5
>
> ; 3:   95
>
> ; ...;

Why can't I get `;` inline with each line other than going it to the second line? Any tips? :) Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You aren't stripping off the newline from the input: `mifFile.write(makeAddress(address, line.strip()))`. Note: you can also use `enumerate()` for your address, e.g.: `for address, line in enumerate(imageFile):`

Comment: Ahh! readline reads the new line too! That's the problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every line you read from imageFile has a newline character included. Using that as HEX, therefore, will put a newline right before the semicolon. Since `.write` does not add another newline automatically, that's why it appears that the newline is just being moved. What you need is to strip the newline from the old one and add it to the new one:

```
for line in imageFile:
    mifFile.write(makeAddress(address, line.strip()) + "\n")
    address = address + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of your code that works. In your example, there was an empty line between each number so I added a test to handle that, because that will result in an incorrect output.

```
def makeAddress(address, HEX):
    return str("\t%s    :   %s;" % (address, HEX));

imageFile = open("Image.txt", "r")
mifFile = open("INSTRUCTION_FILE.mif", "w")

address = 0;

for line in imageFile:
    if line.strip(): # Checks if line is empty string
        mifFile.write(makeAddress(address, line.strip()) + "\n")
        address = address + 1;

imageFile.close()
mifFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic way, use `enumerate` to return a iterator that contains index, and use `strip()` to remove `\n`, then `join` will return a string, which is the concatenation of the strings in the sequence seq:

```
open("output.txt","w").write("\n".join(["{} : {};".format(i,j.strip()) for i,j in enumerate(open('input'))]))
```

If you want a readable way, the above code is equivalent to this:

```
with open('out.csv', 'r') as _input, open("output.txt", "w") as _output:
    lines = ["{} : {};".format(i, j.strip()) for i, j in enumerate(_input)]
    _output.write("\n".join(lines))
```

Output:

```
0   :   AA;
1   :   12;
2   :   C5;
3   :   95;
```

Comment: I wouldn't call a jumbled one-line solution Pythonic. Short is nice, but readable is important. Besides that, it is unpythonic to use `open()` without a `with` block.

Comment: Not sure I would describe `open(...).write(...)` or `enumerate(open(...))` as `pythonic` - `with open(...) as infile, open(..., 'w') as outfile: ...`

Comment: Even with the update, I still don't see why you think a loop isn't pythonic: `for address, line in enumerate(imageFile): mifFile.write("{}: {};\n".format(address, line.strip()))` is perfectly readable and pythonic. Note; you don't need `str(i)` in `format()`, `format()` handles `int`s fine.

Comment: Yes, there's no need to use str()